# Is there anyway to call iOS framework like Vision from java?

Tags: java, ios, swift

I have a project where I want to do object detection in the image provided. Vision framework seems very promising with training data but my problem is I want to do it on the server side rather on at app level.

Is there any way to call the framework from java? is it possible with JNI?

Comment: You can't use any iOS framework on an OS other than iOS, regardless of language.

Comment: Off topic but you can program swift on the server side, lookup vapor or kitura. rmaddy’s comment still applies though